# Y-axis starts from '32' in main window

Tags: java, swing

First of all, here is first question of mine, it marked as duplicate(whereas it was not): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167650/setting-ovals-center-as-mouse-coordinates

I spent my last 9-10 hours to fix it.

I will not copy the whole question(I already shared link), but I will tell you more detail.

My window is 512x512.
When I click upper-left of window, x-axis was around 1-2, y-axis was around 30-35. So, checked low side of window, it was around 510 for y-axis, it's normal.

Here's what I've made:

```
public class Quadtree implements MouseListener{
    
    int x=256,y=256;
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JPanel thePanel = new JPanel(){
        @Override
         protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
           {
              super.paintComponent(g);
              drawCenteredCircle((Graphics2D) g,x,y,30);
                
                    
    }
    
};

public void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics2D g, int x, int y, int r) {
      x = x-(r/2);
      y = y-(r/2);
      g.fillOval(x,y,r,r);
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    new Quadtree();
}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    //  Point p=e.getPoint();
        x=e.getX();
        System.out.println(x);
        y=e.getY();
        System.out.println(y);
        thePanel.repaint();
}
    public Quadtree(){  
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(thePanel);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setSize(512,512);

        frame.addMouseListener(this);   
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Quadtree");
        
    }
}
```

But somehow, in this code which is below, I set oval's y-axis as 0, but it works fine.

```
public void drawCenteredCircle(Graphics2D g, int x, int y, int r) {
      x = x-(r/2);
      y = y-(r/2);
      g.fillOval(x,0,r,r);
    }
```

Output is:

[image]

But when I make mouse click(explained in first sample), circle appears under the mouse.

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Y-axis starts from '32' in main window

```
frame.addMouseListener(this);
```

The frame has a titlebar and border. Don't add the MouseListener to the frame.

Instead add the MouseListener to the panel. Then the mouse point will be relative to the panel, not the frame.

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot. My eye-tears have just made my keyboard wet.